# MariaDB GRANT EXECUTE on *this* procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, sql-grant

**Context:**
I'm currently working on a tool that automatically creates and sets up databases on my MariaDB server. For that I have a 'setup' user. In order to create everything that is needed in the database, the user gets a bunch of privileges on the new database at the start of the creation process. After it is finished, I would like to call a procedures that revokes the privileges again.

For that, I have created a table that contains all the default privileges the user needs. My plan of action is to first REVOKE all privileges from the setup user and then add all privileges from the table, as well as the privilege to execute the reset procedure.

Revoking the privileges works fine. So does adding the privileges from the table. The only problem I have is that whenever I try to `GRANT` the privilege on the reset procedure itself to the setup user, I get a recursion error:

**Code in question:**

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE SchemaName.ResetPrivileges TO `setup`@`10.0.0.4`;
```

*(Called from within the ResetPrivileges Procedure)*

**Error message:**

> SQL Error (1456): Recursive limit 0 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine ResetPrivileges

**Question:**
I'm not quite sure how MariaDB handles `GRANT`, but it seems like the procedure is somehow called (?) once the privilege is granted. Is there any way to give the user permission to this procedure from within the procedure? The only workaround I could think of would be to create another procedure just for granting this privilege and calling it separately, but there has to be a better way, right?

Comment: Do you have a trigger that calls this procedure?

Comment: @Barmar No, I just created this procedure. There are only 2 Triggers on the Server and they are on a different schema and watch tables

Comment: I can't think of a reason why the procedure would be called automatically. But there may be something special about a procedure granting access to itself.